# YankRing in insert mode

Tags: vim, plugins

I'm using vim with YankRing.
Is it possible to paste an element from the YankRing while being in insert mode?
(Like it is possible to paste an element from the usual registers with Ctrl-R + the name of the register.)
Thanks

Comment: Which plugin do you use ? Can you give a link ? Maybe this : https://github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim ?

Comment: Yes, that one.
[link](github.com/vim-scripts/YankRing.vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(NB: I'm not familiar with that particular plugin, so my examples might seem silly.)

When in Insert mode, you can always use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> (see [`i_CTRL-O`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O)) to execute one Normal mode command and immediately get back into Insert mode. So it appears you can just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to use YankRing. Same goes for command-line mode: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> followed by `:YRShow`, for example.